# Nsight Compute profiling of a __device__ function in a kernel

Tags: cuda, kernel, profiling, nvidia, nsight

I am trying to use Nsight Compute to profile kernels in my CUDA code. But how do I profile  functions inside a kernel? Say for example, I have 2 functions (**device** functions) in a kernel (**global**). Nsight compute only profiles the kernel but there is no mention of the functions called inside the kernels.

Comment: You can't profile a device function individually using nsight compute. However you can go to the source page and see correlation of profiler sampling to specific lines of source code.

Comment: If possible, device functions are aggressively inlined for performance, so it makes sense that profiling just the function is hard/impossible (further optimizations - like performing loads as early as possible - might exchange the order of assembly lines belonging to the function and the surrounding kernel).

Answer (score 2):

nsight compute doesn't provide the ability to profile a `__device__` function directly or individually, nor will it present results organized that way.

As indicated in the comments, for a `__device__` function defined in the same compilation unit as the kernel you are profiling, that function may not even exist as a separate or identifiable entity; it will usually get inlined by the compiler, and then subject to further optimization with surrounding code.

You can however associate some profiler information to specific lines of code in the nsight compute UI "Source" page.  [This blog](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/analysis-driven-optimization-analyzing-and-improving-performance-with-nvidia-nsight-compute-part-2/) points that out with an example.